# Convert json to array for any multi dimensions?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if any one knows of a JS function to convert a json array to a javascript array..

How ever the returned json array could be multi dimension or it could be a single dimensional.... so i wanted to find a function that would construct the javascript array to cater to all dimensions?

EDIT: Please don't suggest a library related function i don't use them.

Comment: Why don't you edit your post and show what the input is and what the desired output is?

Comment: Have yoou looked at [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)

Comment: Because the json_encode example i currently have available is only one dimensional, but as im trying to find a function to handle multi dimensional aka (multi purpose).. an example would only give me the answer for that type of array.

Comment: @SpYk3HH i don't use a library im trying to not use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers are already doing this :

`JSON.parse('["foo", ["bar", ["foofoo", "barbar"]]]');`

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON

But you may want something that supports older browsers :
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Did not know modern browsers did that! Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 2):

And if your browser doesn't have that, i found this function once, (somewhere) and it enables JSON.stringify and JSON.parse:

```
var JSON;
JSON||(JSON=function(){function v(x){return x<10?"0"+x:x}Date.prototype.toJSON=function(){return this.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+v(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+v(this.getUTCDate())+"T"+v(this.getUTCHours())+":"+v(this.getUTCMinutes())+":"+v(this.getUTCSeconds())+"Z"};String.prototype.toJSON=Number.prototype.toJSON=Boolean.prototype.toJSON=function(){return this.valueOf()};var i=/[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,m=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,p,
c,y={"\u0008":"\\b","\t":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\u000c":"\\f","\r":"\\r",'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"},C;function I(x){m.lastIndex=0;return m.test(x)?'"'+x.replace(m,function(E){var u=y[E];if(typeof u==="string")return u;return"\\u"+("0000"+(+E.charCodeAt(0)).toString(16)).slice(-4)})+'"':'"'+x+'"'}function J(x,E){var u,A,s=p,t,w=E[x];if(w&&typeof w==="object"&&typeof w.toJSON==="function")w=w.toJSON(x);if(typeof C==="function")w=C.call(E,x,w);switch(typeof w){case "string":return I(w);case "number":return isFinite(w)?
String(w):"null";case "boolean":case "null":return String(w);case "object":if(!w)return"null";p+=c;t=[];if(typeof w.length==="number"&&!w.propertyIsEnumerable("length")){A=w.length;for(x=0;x<A;x+=1)t[x]=J(x,w)||"null";E=t.length===0?"[]":p?"[\n"+p+t.join(",\n"+p)+"\n"+s+"]":"["+t.join(",")+"]";p=s;return E}if(C&&typeof C==="object"){A=C.length;for(x=0;x<A;x+=1){u=C[x];if(typeof u==="string")if(E=J(u,w))t.push(I(u)+(p?": ":":")+E)}}else for(u in w)if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(w,u))if(E=J(u,w))t.push(I(u)+
(p?": ":":")+E);E=t.length===0?"{}":p?"{\n"+p+t.join(",\n"+p)+"\n"+s+"}":"{"+t.join(",")+"}";p=s;return E}}return{stringify:function(x,E,u){E=E;u=u;var A;c=p="";if(typeof u==="number")for(A=0;A<u;A+=1)c+=" ";else if(typeof u==="string")c=u;if((C=E)&&typeof E!=="function"&&(typeof E!=="object"||typeof E.length!=="number"))throw new Error("JSON.stringify");return J("",{"":x})},parse:function(x,E){var u=E;function A(s,t){var w,M,H=s[t];if(H&&typeof H==="object")for(w in H)if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(H,
w)){M=A(H,w);if(M!==undefined)H[w]=M;else delete H[w]}return u.call(s,t,H)}i.lastIndex=0;if(i.test(x))x=x.replace(i,function(s){return"\\u"+("0000"+(+s.charCodeAt(0)).toString(16)).slice(-4)});if(/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(x.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,"@").replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,"]").replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,""))){x=eval("("+x+")");return typeof u==="function"?A({"":x},""):x}throw new Error("JSON.parse");}}}());
JSON.parse=function(){var v=JSON.parse;return function(i,m){try{return v(i,m)}catch(p){return false}}}();
```

uses

```
var bob = {
            key1: "val1",
            key2: "val2"
        }
console.log(JSON, JSON.stringify(bob), JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bob)))
```